# How to skip the default signout page when logging out from Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, logout

When I click the logout button on my web app hosted on Azure, I am logged out and taken to the following page:

[image](Image 1)

It then redirects me to the Azure default signout page (which I don't want to see):

[image](Image 2)

Whenever I click on 'return to the website' it takes me back to my app (without logging in first) but it shows no data in my datatable, which means I'm signed out (in which case I do not want to show the web app in the first place).

When I manually refresh the page, it indeed proves that I was signed out, redirecting me to the Azure AD login page.

So my question is: how do I skip the default Azure signout page with the 'return to the website' link (image 2) and directly go from clicking the signout button in my web app to the Azure AD login page?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the Azure AD will redirect to the page you tell it. When we send a sign-out request using the OpenId connect protocol we need to pass the `post_logout_redirect_uri` parameter, please check whether this parameter is passed correctly. For example, we will pass the default page of web app for the sign-out request.

More detail about sign-out with Azure AD, please refer the link below:

[Send a sign-out request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-a-sign-out-request)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Microsoft support mentioned that 'post_logout_redirect_uri' code will only work if we are controlling the entire logout flow with OWIN. We enabled Authentication through the Azure App service which is handled by the backend service that is injecting authentication into the Web App runtime.

Clicking the 'return to the website' link seemed to trigger a get request that I implemented in the Vue app's 'mounted' lifecycle hook. I removed this get request, and now it seems to work very randomly. Sometimes it asks to re-authenticate hitting the link, other times it doesn't.

Comment: In Safari it works perfectly, in Chrome it only works the first time, after which it doesn't ask to re-authenticate anymore when hitting the 'return to the website' link, only upon manual refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to have to do with caching.

'/.auth/logout' clears cookies but not cache. I solved it by letting the client know that the application is not cachable by adjusting the cache headers:

In the Web.config file add this to the system.Webserver-tag:

```
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
</staticContent>
```

This might not be the optimal solution whenever you favour caching, but in my case it's not too big of a tradeoff.